# How did the original TRS-80 generate video?

Tags: video, trs-80

I'm curious how the original (Model 1) TRS-80 generated video.  I understand that an RF modulator was used but what kind of circuitry did it use to feed the RF modulator?

The TRS-80 Color Computer used an MC6847 IC but I can't find any references to what the original TRS-80 used.  Was it an IC or did it generate video in a similar way the Apple I or Apple II did?

A schematic would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I understand that an RF modulator was used but what kind of circuitry did it use to feed the RF modulator?

To start with, the TRS-80 did *not* use an RF modulator. It delivered composite video (*1) as it was meant to be used with its own brand monitor - which basically was an RCA TV set with the RF part removed, so no need for a modulator (*2).

> The TRS-80 Color Computer used an MC6847 IC but I can't find any references to what the original TRS-80 used.

Like many others, just a bunch of counters and muxes (*3).

> Was it an IC or did it generate video in a similar way the Apple I or Apple II did?

Somewhat, except it was rather straightforward to make it simple instead of squeezing out the max as with the Apple II.

> A schematic would be very helpful as well.

There's even something way better, the original [TRS-80 Technical Manual](http://www.1000bit.it/support/manuali/trs/TRS-80%20Technical%20Manual%20%281978%29%28Radio%20Shack%29%28pdf%29.pdf) which includes a detailed description of each stage (*4).

---

*1 - Well, not really, as the output signal wasn't a standard (1V) composite signal, but generated and transferred at TTL level (5V). The TV set had not only the RF part carved out, but also a little board with an optocoupler added, which not only transposed the signal in level (Again not standard, but this time the 2V signal the remaining logic wanted), but also served as shock protection.

*2 - Then again, there *was* an optional modulator, as the Model 1 could be bought without the screen.

*3 - After all, a 6845 or similar is nothing other than a bunch of counters integrated into a single ... well, **I**ntegrated **C**ircuit :))

*4 - But there are, in addition, many sources for TRS-80 schematics online available ... like [this one](http://ts-inc.dyndns.org/TRS-80%20Model%201%20Schematics/).

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thanks for the technical manual as well!

Comment: Re, "it got a build in CRT." For some definition of "in." I mean, the computer and keyboard were housed in one unit, and the monitor was a separate unit, right?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes. They were. I guess I reword that.

Comment: @Raffzahn Was there not an RF modulator option? I've got a vague feeling from the time that there was, but cannot easily find one online, so maybe not (I had a Video Genie clone, which _did_ have a built-in modulator).

Comment: @TripeHound Not sure. While the very first leaflet makes a seperate calculation of monitor, computer and recorder to finally give a money saving packet price - but with a note telling that later sales prices may be different - later catalogues only offer the Model 1 only as one position at one price, always including computer and screen. After allm TV sets where acomodity at Tandy. EACA in contrast wanted to compete just with the computer, so no need to get into TV production, so it offered RF as well as standard voltage composite.

Comment: Great info ... and I loved re-reading the original manual! Here is the spec sheet for the IC in question also: [MD6847 Video Display Generator (pdf)][1] 


  [1]: https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/ideas/mc6847.pdf

Comment: Great info ... and I loved re-reading the original manual! Here is the spec sheet for the IC in question also: [MD6847 Video Display Generator (pdf)](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/ideas/mc6847.pdf)

Comment: @Skeptycal Except that chip was not used in the TRS-80

Comment: Oops: I folded Skeptycal's 6845 spec sheet into the answer, before I noticed Raffzan's comment that it wasn't used in the TRS-80.  Please reject my edit.

Comment: @WayneConrad No harm done.